# Behat: expect to send an email

Tags: phpunit, behat

Most of the few Behat examples I saw test for an object property, like

```
/**
 * @Then the overall basket price should be £:price
 */
public function theOverallBasketPriceShouldBePs($price)
{
    PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertSame(
        floatval($price),
        $this->basket->getTotalPrice()
    );
}
```

But what if my user story goes something like this:

```
Given, a user has received pdf1
When 48 hours have passed since the download
Then the application must send pdf2 to the user
```

How am I supposed to test for the `@then` step in this case - mocking and using PHPUnit expectations? I somehow get the feeling that I completely misunderstand something here.

Comment: You must have some code that checks if 48 hours have passed, right? Mock the part of the code that checs for the date so that it assumes that 48 hours have passed and triggers the second email.

Comment: @gvf Right, I'm more interested though how to test mail sending in BDD (the `Then` step of my user story). I will be looking in to Mailtrap, because it seems to do what is required here.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use Mailtrap. BDD is for testing your domain logic, the actual sending of an email is more an infrastructure thing. What I would do is mock or inject a fake sender class and check that your logic called it. If you want to actually test that SMTP is working, I would do another kind of test. Ideally all your Behat suite should be able to run 'offline'

Comment: @gvf You got a point there. My first approach was to use PHPUnit mocking and expectations (ie. that the `send` method was called), but I couldn't find any examples of this being done in a Behat context.

Comment: `What I would do is mock or inject a fake sender class and check that your logic called it` > I'm not sure how to test this, because it means that my logic (domain model) would have a dependency on the mailer.

Comment: No, your domain logic would have a dependency on a mailer interface, how you implement that interface is up to you: it can be a fake sender, smtp, mailchimp.

Comment: @gvf I see what you are saying, but a domain object shouldn't have any dependencies on services or infrastructure in my opinion - it shouldn't care whether it is being sent by email or sms or whatever. It should be an entity with behaviour, nothing else. Since BDD/Behat is about testing domain logic as you say, I am going to test exactly this, nothing else.

Comment: What I mean is that your domain logic has a behaviour that requires notifying users, how that notification is sent is an infrastructure thing. So in Behat you can test that your domain logic calls a 'Notificator' class, what you don't have to test is if that notificator class actually sends emails via smtp, or via push etc. But notifying users IS part of your domain logic, so it should be tested IMO.

Comment: @gvf I guess we have different opinions here, because I want to go with a "pure" domain object. Which means I am not going to test if my domain object calls a mailer method, but whether it's behaviour related to the sending of a message returns the expected value, ie. whether the method `isEligibleForNextProduct` returns `True`. If that's the case, I have tested my domain logic, and the implementation of that logic is then a service/infrastructure thing.

Comment: Are you saving any data in db in your tests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188662/discussion-between-michael-and-gvf).

Answer (score 0):

Since I want my domain object to not have any dependencies, I opted to purely test the domain logic that involves sending messages, nothing more. As far as I understand it, this is what BDD is about. In my `Lead` entity:

```
public function isEligibleForNextMessage( int $interval ) {
 if ( /* Do Logic */ ) :
   return TRUE;
 endif;

 return FALSE;
}
```

Then in my `LeadContext`:

```
/**
 * @Then the application must send pdf2 to the user
 */
public function sendNextMessage() {

    Assert::assertTrue( $this->Lead->isEligibleForNextMessage( 172800 ) );
}
```

This should be be sufficient to test the above user story regarding the time interval.